# Delphi, cursor on pop-up menu

Tags: delphi, курсор

В ресурсы запихиваю ани курсор, предварительно его обработав (gfi была тема).
так в тхт файловом ресурса:

```
55 21 "poi.ani"
```

после, ресурс подключаю к проге + подкл. примерно так при создании формы

```
Screen.Cursors[1]:=LoadCursor(HInstance, pChar(55));
Screen.Cursor:=1;
```

все красиво, курсор вижу, если на форму навести

Вопрос: на форме есть некий элемент, у него свой pop-up menu.
когда меню вызываю по правой клавише мыши - на меню курсор обычный.

Как и меню присвоить курсор формы? И почему наследования нет?

Comment: Есть `form1.cursor = 1`, но если вы его кем-то перетёрли - будет другой. Каждый hwnd (TWinControl-потомок) может задавать свой курсор, наследуется или нет - не помню, не сталкивался.

Comment: Если проблема присвоением курсора форме не решается, то выхода у вас два 1) (правильный) поставть хук на создание окна SetWindowHookEx + WH_CBT, ловить новосозданое окно, и задать ему курсор через стиль (SetClassLong + GCL_HCURSOR). 2) (упрощённый) по таймеру каждые 200мс перетирать курсор глобально на нужный вам через SetCursor или Screen.  (Просто меню имеет своё окно с "личным" HWND и стилями, а курсор привязан к HWND-окна поэтому так сложно).

Comment: Можно попробовать в PopupMenu1Popup записать `SetCursor(PopupMenu1->Handle, ваш курсор );`